# Laravel: How does this code work when resolving service?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Specifically, I'm looking at this bit `$this->instances[$abstract]` from below, but I'm not sure how `isset($this->instances[$abstract]` is being evaluated to true, even though the index doesn't appear to exist.

`Illuminate\Container\Container`:

```
public function make($abstract, array $parameters = [])
{
    $abstract = $this->getAlias($this->normalize($abstract));

    if (isset($this->instances[$abstract])) {
        return $this->instances[$abstract]; // <-- this!
    }
   ...
}
```

The array property `$instances` doesn't have the `$abstract` index set, but it is still returning the appropriate service. In my case, `$abstract` is `cache`, and returned object is `Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager`. What kind of magic is this?

Xdebug breakpoint at a `Cache::has($key)` call below. `$this->instances` shown and `$abstract` is `cache`.

[image: xdebug]

Comment: Are you sure **that** particular return is what's returning your cache service? I took a look at https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php#L612 and the `...` you've elided contains logic to build a new instance if it isn't yet present (`$object = $this->build($concrete, $parameters);` etc.).

Comment: @ceejayoz I added a screenshot of xdebug in the post. It is returning `$this->instances[$abstract]`.

Comment: Using the cache service will likely trigger that code multiple times. Are you sure it's the **Cache** call that's triggering that line in xdebug? Laravel's startup will access things like the Config service. Try adding a `\Log::debug('RETURNING ' . $abstract)` line before the return (and one below the `if(isset())` block) and see, perhaps. I remain skeptical that PHP's `isset` is broken...

Comment: Found the problem. `var_display_max_children` setting was set to 20. Good old `dd()` helped.